# How to find the index value of a li that has a particular text in it ?

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<div id="vertical-tabs">
        <ul class="tabs">

            <li id="tbli" ><a href="bid=32&bname=City+Cinema&cid=11" target="__blank">City Cinema</a></li>

            <li id="tbli" ><a href="bid=33&bname=Happy+Land&cid=11" target="__blank">Happy Land</a></li>

            <li id="tbli" ><a href="bid=34&bname=I+Race&cid=11" target="__blank">I Race</a></li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

Above is my html.I need to know the index value of li that contains text Happy Land . So that i can use it in my other function 
`tabClick($("#vertical-tabs li:eq(1)"));`     where eq(1) is the index value. I need to change it dynamically with respect to text in it.

Comment: Ids have to be unique. Use a class instead of `id=tbli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$('li:contains(Happy Land)').index()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aN25y/)

A more accurate version will be

```
var index = $('.tabs li').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Happy Land'
}).index();

console.log('index', index)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/whx6y/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.index()` like

```
$('.tabs li a').each(function(){
     if($(this).text() == "Happy Land") {
         alert($(this).index());
     }
});
```

And makesure that `Ids` are **unique**.

Orelse you can also try with `:contains` like

```
var indx = $('.tabs li a:contains("Happy Lane")').index()
alert(indx);
```